# Usage of google.script.run in custom menues

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to implement custom HTML-menu in Google Sheets. There is drop-down list populated with values from named range via function ***getValuesForRngName()***. Upon selection of value in list, the script should retrieve the range from the sheet again, determine the price and populate the price into a text box servicePrice. However, the problem is that this line of code "***values = google.script.run.getValuesForRngName('ServiceList');***" is not retrieving anything.

Could you please suggest how to make it work?

HTML code is provided below:

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Select Service:</td>
        <td><select name="servicesMD" id="servicesMD" onChange="retrieveServicePrice(this);"></select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><br/><br/>

          <script type="text/javascript">
            function onSuccess(values) {
              var option, dropDown;
              for (i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
                dropDown = document.getElementById("servicesMD");
                option = document.createElement("option");
                dropDown.options.add(option);
                option.value = values[i][0]; // service ID
                option.text = values[i][1]; // service Name 
              }
            }

            function populate() {
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getValuesForRngName('ServiceList');
            }
          </script>
          Service Price: <input id="servicePrice" name="servicePrice" type="text" /><br/><br/>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('load', populate());

  function retrieveServicePrice(element) {
    var selectionIndex;
    var values;
    values = google.script.run.getValuesForRngName('ServiceList');
    selectionIndex = document.forms[0].action = element.options[element.selectedIndex].getAttribute("value");
    document.getElementById("servicePrice").value = values[selectionIndex][3]; // should retrieve price of service
  }
</script>
```

GAS code is below:

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show custom menu', 'openServiceSalesForm')
      .addToUi();
}
function openServiceSalesForm() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(400);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Service sales form');
} 

// RangeList
function getValuesForRngName(rngName) {
  var rngValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(rngName).getValues();
  return rngValues;
}
```

Comment: rngValues is an two dimensional array.  If there's only one then it would be referenced by rngValues[0][0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that, the columns in the range ServiceList are in the following order `Service ID |  Service Name | Price`

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', populate());
    var serviceID;

    function retrieveServicePrice(element) {
        serviceID = element;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(injectValuesIntoHTML).getValuesForRngName('ServiceList');
    }
    window.injectValuesIntoHTML = function(values) {
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (serviceID == values[i][0]) {
                document.getElementById("servicePrice").value = values[i][2]; // should retrieve price of service
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<select name="servicesMD" id="servicesMD" onChange="retrieveServicePrice(this.value);">
```